# How to render a 3d object in a texture

Tags: rendering, texturing, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, mathematics

So I have somewhat of a 3d space inside this texture and I wanted to know if it is possible to draw a 3d sphere inside of

how do I tackle this with nodes if possible at all, should I use a Parametric Sphere Formula?

[image]

the end goal a sphere inside a sphere

[image]

Comment: You mean a faked 3D sphere which is flat but with the good light/shadow effects?

Comment: It looks possible in theory. But I'm unsure if there is a node set up that could achieve it.

Comment: I might attempt making a shader that is transparent in the center (maybe with the fresnel or layer weight node plugged into a color ram, plugged into a mix shader).  Then place a sphere in the middle, or using the compositor to layer the outer sphere over a render of the inner one.

Comment: @lemon yes, hopefully from all angles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't perfect as the shading is a bit off. But maybe you can improve on this:

(If you add a vector mapping node to the object texture coordinates you can scale the inner sphere.)
[image: Sphere in a sphere shader]

All that is necessary is the dot product into the bump node, but this causes the auto smooth shading to go away. So the color ramp is trying to add smoothing back, but not quite perfectly.

Comment: this is pretty cool, i think that the shading issue is an eevee problem, it doesnt show in cycles